# Google Web Toolkit With Line/Pie Graphs

Tags: gwt, graph, charts

Currently I am using Google Charts with Google Web Toolkit but I wanted to explore other options for graphing. I looked into jGraph and the gwt extension mxgraph but that seems to only support actual graphs for flowcharts/diagraming?

Is there any other library (other than Google charts) that I can use to visually show line/pie graphs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at high level visualization charts

http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/

And wonderful showcase here

http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/showcase/

Hope that helps.Good luck.